# Update table using direct calling of query got an error

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb

this is my function..

```
    public static void expMember(){
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 

    java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqldate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String a= formatter.format(sqldate);  

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery (" update tbl_member set exp_status = 'true' where renewDate="+a);

    int result = query.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println(result);
    }
```

error shows..

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tbl_member is not mapped [ update 
 tbl_member set exp_status = 'true' where renewDate=2014-02-25]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,I think you r missing  single colon for date

```
public static void expMember(){
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 

    java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqldate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String a= formatter.format(sqldate);  

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery (" update tbl_member set exp_status = 'true' where renewDate="+"'" + a + "';";

    int result = query.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Error is becuase u have not mapped your tbl_member, please map your table memeber

Comment: have u mapped tbl_member main problem is there , exception says that tbl_member isnot mapped

Comment: mapped as <mapping class="com.habitz.librarymanagement.domain.Member" />

Answer (score 1):

check the mappings in all the .xml config files regarding the entity "tbl_member".

Have you tried to google search [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hibernate%20table%20not%20mapped&oq=hibernate%20table%20no&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6760j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: here domain Member is annotated via Entity not as xml file